# Unable to check the RAM usage per user

Tags: 12.04, ram

I was recently wanting to check the RAM usage per connected user on my server but could not find a way out. Please suggest some way.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 ps aux | grep $USER | awk '{memory +=$4}; END {print memory }'
```

- `ps aux`: To see every process on the system using BSD syntax.
- `$USER` is the current user; change it to an actual name if you need someone else.

Now for the magical part:

- awk creates a variable called memory and adds column 4 of the output of `ps auxU $USER` and when it ENDs it prints the calculated amount.

---

Addition: Graphical method.

> **[smem memory reporting tool](http://www.selenic.com/smem/)**
>
> smem is a tool that can give numerous reports on memory usage on Linux
>   systems. Unlike existing tools, smem can report proportional set size
>   (PSS), which is a more meaningful representation of the amount of
>   memory used by libraries and applications in a virtual memory system.
>
> Because large portions of physical memory are typically shared among
>   multiple applications, the standard measure of memory usage known as
>   resident set size (RSS) will significantly overestimate memory usage.
>   PSS instead measures each application's "fair share" of each shared
>   area to give a realistic measure.
>
> smem has many features:
>
> system overview listing listings by process, mapping, user filtering
>   by process, mapping, or user configurable columns from multiple data
>   sources configurable output units and percentages configurable headers
>   and totals reading live data from /proc reading data snapshots from
>   directory mirrors or compressed tarballs lightweight capture tool for
>   embedded systems built-in chart generation smem has a few
>   requirements:
>
> - a reasonably modern kernel (> 2.6.27 or so)
> - a reasonably recent version of Python (2.4 or so)
> - the matplotlib library for chart generation (optional, auto-detected)
>
> **Using smem**
>
> - show user-oriented view:  `smem -u`
>     (more in the link)'

Installation:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: is there any easier way to do the same??

Comment: Then you need to explain what you consider easy. This method works on server (and that is the system where these kind of questions are mostly asked). Have a look at this: http://www.selenic.com/smem/ Is that something for you?

Comment: I found the same thing here as well: http://www.coolcoder.in/2014/01/ram-utilization-per-userapplication-in.html

Comment: @evaipar that is the command line of what the button does in my answer :) Nice find!  And do not forget to upvote if it suits your needs ;)